# Why i am getting Syntax error on tokem "<td>" , delete this token in my JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets, scriptlet

i am trying to retrieve db table data into  table but i am getting syntax error at

```
<body>
      <tr>
         if(!resultset.next()) {
              out.println("Sorry, could not find that publisher. ");
           } else {     
            while(resultset.next())
            {
            <tr>
            <td class="auto-style9"><%=resultset.getInt(1)%> </td> 
            <td class="auto-style10"><%=resultset.getString(2)%></td>
            <td class="auto-style11"><%=resultset.getString(3)%></td>
            <td class="auto-style11"><%=resultset.getString(4)%></td>
        </tr>   
            }
           } 
     %>
      </table>
</body>
```

Comment: you added the `-->` in your code and we can't tell whether it's part of the code (and caused the error) or you just added it to indicate where the error is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed `html` code with `jsp` code.

It should be :

```
<%
if(!resultset.next()) {
    out.println("Sorry, could not find that publisher. ");
} else {
    while(resultset.next())
    {
%>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style9"><%=resultset.getInt(1)%> </td> 
        <td class="auto-style10"><%=resultset.getString(2)%></td>
        <td class="auto-style11"><%=resultset.getString(3)%></td>
        <td class="auto-style11"><%=resultset.getString(4)%></td>
    </tr>
<%
    }
} 
%>
</table>
```

Comment: then how can i retrieve entire table row by row?